# How to properly mimic IAuthenticationHandler while unit testing ASP.NET Core controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to unit test a simple method like `Login` this in my `AccountController` based on [this](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/test/MusicStore.Test/ManageControllerTest.cs) test from [MusiStore](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore) example.

```
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginArgumentsModel model)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return BadRequest();
   }
   var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
   if (result.Succeeded)
   {
      return Ok();
   }
return StatusCode(422); // Unprocessable Entity
}
```

For that I need to use both `UserManager` and `SignInManager` which eventually forces me to use write a substitute for `IAuthenticationHandler` for using in `HttpAuthenticationFeature`. In the end test turns out like this:

```
public class AccountControllerTestsFixture : IDisposable
{
    public IServiceProvider BuildServiceProvider(IAuthenticationHandler handler)
    {
        var efServiceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase().BuildServiceProvider();

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(b => b.UseInMemoryDatabase().UseInternalServiceProvider(efServiceProvider));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(o =>
        {
            o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            o.Password.RequiredLength = 3;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            // IHttpContextAccessor is required for SignInManager, and UserManager
        var context = new DefaultHttpContext();

        context.Features.Set<IHttpAuthenticationFeature>(new HttpAuthenticationFeature { Handler = handler });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor>(new HttpContextAccessor()
        {
            HttpContext = context
        });

        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }

    public Mock<IAuthenticationHandler> MockSignInHandler()
    {
        var handler = new Mock<IAuthenticationHandler>();
        handler.Setup(o => o.AuthenticateAsync(It.IsAny<AuthenticateContext>())).Returns<AuthenticateContext>(c =>
        {
            c.NotAuthenticated();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });
        handler.Setup(o => o.SignInAsync(It.IsAny<SignInContext>())).Returns<SignInContext>(c =>
        {
            c.Accept();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });

        return handler;
    }
    public void Dispose(){}
}
```

and this:

```
public class AccountControllerTests : IClassFixture<AccountControllerTestsFixture>
{
    private AccountControllerTestsFixture _fixture;

    public AccountControllerTests(AccountControllerTestsFixture fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Login_When_Present_Provider_Version()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockedHandler = _fixture.MockSignInHandler();
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = _fixture.BuildServiceProvider(mockedHandler.Object);

        var userName = "Flattershy";
        var userPassword = "Angel";
        var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userName) };

        var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        var userManagerResult = await userManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser() { Id = userName, UserName = userName, TwoFactorEnabled = false }, userPassword);

        Assert.True(userManagerResult.Succeeded);

        var signInManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();

        AccountController controller = new AccountController(userManager, signInManager);

        // Act
        var model = new LoginArgumentsModel { UserName = userName, Password = userPassword };
        var result = await controller.Login(model) as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);
    }

}
```

Both multiple mocking `IAuthenticationHandler` and creating multiple classes implementing `IAuthenticationHandler` for each test in different way looks a bit too far for me, but I also want to use serviceProvider and do not want to mock `userManager` and `signInManager`. While tests written this way seem to work I want to know if there is any not supercomplicated way to use `CookieAuthenticationHandler`or anything else that behaves the way application with `app.UseIdentity()` does.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just mock the SignInManager, stick it in the service collection, and setup the one call to `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false)` to return the results you want to test for your controller?

Comment: I can and did this a few times but it does not feel right to me, and I think  such call will not affect mocked `HttpContext` so a more complex controller might not behave in a proper way. Also I want it to be as close to original behavior as possible and I am not very good at mocking objects.